# PrintNormal() Issue 'It is not Initialized'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, point-of-sale, pos-for-.net

Current C# POS.NET Printing Issue:

`PrintNormal()` Throws Exception =  'It is not initialized'
   `CheckHealth`      = 'It is not initialized' 
   'It is not initialized' exception when Printing to Epson TM-T88IV

Using POS for .NET 1.12 and the Epson OPOS ADK for .NET (v1.11.9) service-objects
Successfully able to Open, Claim and Set the DeviceEnabled-true for PosPrinter

**Issue** sending anything to the printer after this
PrintNormal() results in a 'It is not initialized' exception being thrown. 
CheckHealth Utility that came with the Epson OPOS ADK results in exactly the same error. When using PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt the exception is 'The specified station is not mounted."

printer prints fine using direct parallel
printer itself prints

How can we not throw the exemption with the message - 'It is not initialized'?

```
void K8POSPrint()
{
    /// <summary>
    /// PosPrinter object
    /// </summary>
    PosPrinter m_Printer = null;
    try
    {
        //Use a Logical Device Name which has been set on the SetupPOS.
        string strLogicalName = "PosPrinter";
        try
        {
            //Create PosExplorer
            PosExplorer posExplorer = new PosExplorer();
            DeviceInfo deviceInfo = null;

            try
            {
                // Device Info is not null when the printer has the logical name
                deviceInfo = posExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter, strLogicalName);
                m_Printer = (PosPrinter)posExplorer.CreateInstance(deviceInfo);
            }
            catch (Exception ExDevice)
            {
            }

            //Open the device
            m_Printer.Open();
            //Get the exclusive control right for the opened device. Then the device is disable from other application.
            m_Printer.Claim(1000);
            //Enable the device.
            m_Printer.DeviceEnabled = true;
            //    ////CheckHealth.
            //m_Printer.CheckHealth(Microsoft.PointOfService.HealthCheckLevel.Interactive);
            //    //As using the PrintNormal method, send strings to a printer, and print it [\n] is the standard code for starting a new line.
            /// Current Issue Next Line thows an exception - 'It is not initialized' 
            m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "Hey Now OPOS for .NET\n");
            // the next line would throw the exception 'The specified station is not mounted.'
            // m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Slip,"Hey Now Slip OPOS.NET\n");
        }
        catch (PosControlException)
        {

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Additional Information:
    Programs installed while attempting to print on the pos printer are:
 
1. Installed APD4 Printer Driver Epson TI88IV 
    
APD_412EWM.exe
    https://www.epsonexpert.com/ee/techRes/index.htm?ProductId=570 

     After this set in control panel printers I can select the printer's properties & print a test to the printer successfully. 

2. Installed Microsoft POS.NET 1.12

     POSfor.NET.msi 
    http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=eaae202a-0fcc-406a-8fde-35713d7841ca 

3. Installed Epson OPOS ADK v2.67

    ADK267ER4.exe

    https://www.epsonexpert.com/ee/appDev/appDevOPOS.htm 

4. Installed EPSON OPOS ADK for .NET 1.11.8
    
OPOSN 1 11 18.exe
    https://www.epsonexpert.com/ee/appDev/appDevOPOS.htm 

5. Installed OPOS Common Control Objects 1.13.001

    OPOS_CCOs_1.13.001.msi

    http://monroecs.com/oposccos_current.htm 

6. SetupPOS - Added device & Logical Name
7. Check Health still throws the errors
     It is not initialized
     OPOS_E_ILLEGAL 10007 (0x00002717)

Comment: I think your try catch nesting is the problem, you don't get the real problem here. Try to remove some of the Try catch codes and leave only one. Then you'll see what the real problem is.

Comment: Do you have a OPOS printer named PosPrinter set up? You can check in the registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\OLEforRetail\ServiceOPOS\PosPrinter` there should be a sub key named `PosPrinter`. Is the printer setup in Windows in Printers and Devices, if it is try removing? From what I recall if the printer is set up in Windows it will not always work in OPOS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might not be software, but hardware.  I saw a similar question (at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/446fd4cc-db6b-4822-b3c8-7d9a98bf7eb4/it-is-not-initialized-when-trying-to-printnormal?forum=posfordotnet), where the developer was using an extension cable which was not parallel.  As soon as he connected the parallel cable directly to the printer (without the extension cable), his software worked.  This was after he called Epson and ordered a newer printer, because they told him his original printer was not compatible with .NET, so that could also be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error "It is not initialized" on brand new Epson TM-T88VI.
The printer came with IDN Card and default the ethernet card was partially blocked. You can use the ethernet card to connect to "Epson Net Config", but it did not work when you try to print by OPOS ADK for NET.
The solution was to set switches on IDN Card as:

| DS1 | DS2 | DS3 | DS4 | DS5 | DS6 | DS7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OFF | OFF | OFF | OFF | ON | ON | ON |

Make sure Power OFF when you changing the switches.